# 'GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h' file not found in AIRGoogleMapPolygon.h

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-mapview, react-native-ios

I am a beginner with react native and doing mapview I am having a problem

> 'GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h' file not found in AIRGoogleMapPolygon.h

Please help me.

I was working from the link https://codeburst.io/react-native-google-map-with-react-native-maps-572e3d3eee14